# Import a class from different folder levels - Python

Tags: python, class, import, subdirectory

I am writing a sequence to sequence model and I have the following directory structure

```
MyProject/
     models/ 
          - __init__.py
          - Encoder.py
     train/
          - __init__.py
          - Train.py
```

While in Train.py, I cannot import the classes BiDirectionalEncoder from Encoder.py despite trying to use the following syntax

```
from models.Encoder import BiDirectionalEncoder
```

For the line above I get the error "
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'"

```
from ..models.Encoder import BiDirectionalEncoder
```

For the last line I get the error "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

Is there are neat way to fix this? I dont want to use any sys.path.append() to force paths to be added
I am using Python 3.7.6 in Spyder 4.0.1
Thanks!

Comment: `from models.Encoder import BiDirectionalEncoder ` is it not working?

Comment: No its not. And that is a bit frustrating and surprising too, I cant figure out what is wrong.

Comment: what is your current directory file when you run the program? if you are trying to run from `Train.py` then the system can't find the main My project path.

Comment: @Wajih were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: @GauriShankarBadola Nope mate. Could not fix it.

Comment: Can you zip the proj directory and share it with me?

Comment: @GauriShankarBadola unfortunately I cant share it.

Comment: @Wajih
I tried to replicate the project structure here.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1kChcz2n5FnTfgivwklyY1L6LIJusGA8C


Download this and when I run train,py in pyCharm, I get `im in models.__init__.py` in console.

Comment: I tried. Seems that this a problem with Spyder. Thanks for the solution thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the same package you can do relative import but since you are going out of your current package, you need to do absolute imports.

```
from MyProject.models.Encoder import BiDirectionalEncoder
```

Comment: You mean I add the project path name to the imports? That is going to be clunky. I am not sure. Let me try this.

Comment: Yes, as the error message suggest..

**ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package**

You can not import outside your current package unless it is added in sys.path or PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Hmmm. Now it says  "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MyProject'" I do have a __init.py__ under the root of MyProject folder

Comment: Turns out to be a problem with spyder

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any IDE (eg. pycharm) you need to set (my project) as source boot directory
else you need to check your BASE_DIR in settings.py

and then you will be able to import the model.

from models.Encoder import BiDirectionalEncoder

and yes if you want to access module from other environment below is the link
for ways of accessing and sharing modules.

[python module:- importing(accessing) creating and sharing](https://stackabuse.com/python-modules-creating-importing-and-sharing/)

hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: I dont want to force paths as I mentioned in my question. Esp when I deploy the code in some other environment or machine